# Mongodb Book trade website listing not working

Tags: python, reactjs, node.js, database, mongodb

we are working on a book swapping website that uses mongodb, flask, reactjs and python. We tried to sign up and login on the website and it shows on the mongodb compass however, when we try to add a listing, it doesnt show and it shows this error when we check the network.

here is the code in the createlisting.js file

```
const tryCreateListing = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const responseProfile = await axios.get(
        process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE + "/user",
        {
          headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
        }
      );
      console.log("PROFILE RESPONSE:", responseProfile);
      const userId = responseProfile.data.profile._id;
      const imageUrls = await uploadFiles(images);
      const responseCreateListing = await axios.post(
        process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE + "/createlisting",
        {
          user_id: userId,
          title: title,
          isbn: isbn,
          price: price,
          description: description,
          condition: condition,
          img: imageUrls,
        },
        { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } }
      );
      console.log("Create listing response: ", responseCreateListing);
      if (responseCreateListing.status === 202) setSuccess(true);
    } catch (error) {
      setSuccess(false);
      console.log("Create listing error: ", error);
    }
  };
```

this shows on the network

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)
CreateListing.js:194 Create listing error:  AxiosError

We are looking for others solution like changing the code or using other tutorials to perform the task but we sill can't solve it. Our goal is when the user clicks the add listing, it will go into the listings database

Comment: Do you have any control over the API or are you sure your problem is in the front end?
Maybe the proper endpoint is "/createListing"?

Comment: it is now working I made a .env file with this REACT_APP_API_BASE

but other parts of the code is not working like swapping and etc.

Comment: Nice job! That was a good find. Keep applying the same thinking you did to find that bug, and I'm sure you'll find all the rest.